# Death cases of computer technician

Tags: mystery, computer-puzzle, steganography

Police found the body of a computer technician in front of his computer, with a belly wound. There was a possibility of the victim bleeding to death after being stabbed with a sharp object. There were no signs of damage on the windows or doors, which indicated that the killer was someone close to the victim. The dead body was found holding the keyboard and mouse. The monitor displayed the explorer and command prompt. On the user folder of his computer (Windows 8), police found one image file with the name **img.gif**. They also found blood on the following keyboard keys:

> Enter Shift **Space** Alt F7 = / **.** A B **C** E F **G** **I** L M O P **R** U Y

The bold keys indicates that the key has more blood than others, and here is the image (img.gif):

[image: img.gif]

The questions is, who killed the technician?

- the layout of the keyboard was QWERTY
- the command prompt was open, but without any text; apparently the victim just deleted the history by Alt+F7
- there is a possibility that the victim or someone else deleted some files
- the culprit's name is on the list
- the keys are not in sequence

Transcript of image:

```
Aisyah P       08085733163110 
Putut H        085648887714 
Nur Komaroh    72346874 
Rossa Riasa    085733265290 
Ullah Prihasti 08563146198 
Sela-ajah      083857251129 / 085857311079 
Fonisah S      083857921353 
Febrina H      085733224890 
Sriong Putri K 71488407
```

please, only open the spoiler text if you think this riddle is kinda difficult

clue 1:

> by solving what was written by the technician, it will be easier to solve this puzzle, but you need a little knowledge of computers for this, if you do not have it, you could just try to find out what is contained in this picture.

clue 2:

> steganography

more spoiler text will come...

Comment: The technician should've been fired for saving a photo in `gif` format anyway. Maybe that's the reason he's dead.

Comment: The setup of him holding the mouse and keyboard is highly unlikely...

Comment: Do not take this too seriously, this is not real case, it just depicting that he use mouse and keyboard to make the his death message.

Comment: it must have something to do with the numbers underneath the names on the list but what? and the pressed keys should be read in reverse because the last thing he did was use alt F4 so the first key he pressed was the Y

Comment: @Bert-jan nothing to do with keys sequence, I just order it for easy reading.

Comment: @nyongrand I have edited your question and fixed the grammar mistakes. I hope I didnt remove or misrepresent something. If I have please feel free to change it back

Comment: @nyongrand The keyboard layout *is* relevant for the `=` and `/` and `.` keys.

Comment: Is there any blood on the mouse?

Comment: @MartinBüttner, ah yes, that make sense, sorry, I never use any other keyboards layout

Comment: @Psychemaster, yes

Comment: does the blood looks like split into it or pressed?

Comment: Does No HP mean home phone number? In that image?

Comment: I have created a chat room for this puzzle: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18876/death-cases-of-computer-technician

Comment: @nyongrand can you provide a transcript of the image? Its hard to read some of the characters in the image.

Comment: OK guys, here is the transcript.
Aisyah P 
08085733163110 
Putut H 
085648887714 
Nur Komaroh 
72346874 
Rossa Riasa 
085733265290 
Ullah Prihasti 
08563146198 
Sela-ajah 
083857251129 / 085857311079 
Fonisah S 
083857921353 
Febrina H 
085733224890 
Sriong Putri K 
71488407

Comment: Are `shift` and `alt` left or right?

Comment: I am surprised nobody else seems to have picked up this puzzle yet. I find it very intriguing - just don't have any solution idea yet. @nyongrand, do you think you could provide another spoiler-hint, or are you happy with waiting it out.@all others: come on guys, not even a suggestions? We could try to put forces together here...

Comment: @BmyGuest I tried to make this puzzle not easy to guess

Comment: Haven't looked at this for a long time (just fav'ed it). Now that I've seen the solution: great puzzle! (Great solution too)

Comment: Apparently the OP mixed up Stenography (shorthand writing) with Steganograhpy (information hiding).

Comment: Are you from Indonesia @nyongrand? Because those are Indonesian names and Indonesian languages. "Nama" is Indonesian for name.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I assume that bold keys pressed two times, so we have:

```
Enter Shift Space Space Alt F7 = / . . A B C C E F G G I I L M O P R R U Y
```

First, I substract the image name from the key list, IMG.GIF, and ALT F7 (command to clear cmd history), now we have:

```
Enter Shift Space Space = / . A B C C E L O P R R U Y
```

because command prompt windows is open, I assume the victim write some cmd command, then by looking at this page http://ss64.com/nt/ as refference, there is 3 possible command written by the victim

```
ARP : Address Resolution Protocol
CLS : Clear the scree
COPY: Copy one or more files to another location`
```

the ARP and CLS is unlikely, so my best bet is `COPY`, now we have:

```
Enter Shift Space Space = / . A B C E L R R U
```

Then, because `/` key is also there, I asssume the victim use `COPY` command with options, by looking at the `COPY` command refference, http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html, there is three possible options used by the victim:

```
/A:  ASCII text file (default)
/B:  Binary file copy - will copy extended characters.
/L:  If source is a symbolic link copy the link to the target instead of the actual file the source link points to.
```

`/A` is unlikely, `/L` is unlikely too I think, my best bet is `/B` now we have

```
Enter Shift Space Space = . A C E L R R U
```

I do not have any clue after this, but by writting the command together, I have:

```
COPY IMG.GIF + [. A C E L R R U] /B
```

hey [. A C E L R R U] must be some filename too, maybe its `CLUE.RAR`

```
COPY IMG.GIF + CLUE.RAR /B
```

Now I have complete command, I google for `copy /b image` the first result take me here http://www.wikihow.com/Store-a-Rar-or-Zip-in-an-Image-File

if you read the page, you will know that this command store archive in image file, this is some kind of steganography.

> I download the image, then rename it to `CLUE.RAR`, then open it, BANG... it's open, the archive contain one file `clue.wav` I extract it, and open it with music player, there you can hear someone says "the answer is inside this file" with background sound which not clear, this is backmasking technique, if you reverse playback this sound, you will hear "killer is febrina", and that is, the killer is "FEBRINA H"

Comment: Nice analysis, congratulations you managed to solve this puzzle.

Comment: Brilliant answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I would have to decided on a prime suspect, it would be

> Ullah Prihasti

This is currently based on some rather loose clues and not strong facts, though. My reasoning is:

Assumption #1:

> More blood should potentially indicated later in typing, but also, that the victim is obviously already closer to death than to life. As a result, there is a higher chance of mistyping those letters. Assuming that he is "slumping to ground", I'd guess the likelihood for the "true" key being one row above the actually hit one is higher, but one shouldn't rule out other close-bye keys.
>  So, chances are that C should be D/F,  G should be R/T/Y, I should be 8/9 and R should 4/5.

Assumption #2:

> Another fact is the number of keys. Leaving aside space and others, there have been at least 14 characters been typed. Now, assuming that a dying man is not wasting his time on complex riddles, the guess would be that he tries typing a name. This narrows the list of suspects to those with longer names, in particular "Ullah Prihasti" and "Sriong Putri K".

And drawn conclusion:

> Both have less than 14 characters in their name, so the telephone numbers possibly count. (Although it's odd that a dying man tries to identify his murdere by his number.) Only the keys "I" and "R" are close to the numbers, and most likely 89 or 45. Of the two mentions above,  Sriong's number starts with 714... while Ullah's starts with 085... which is by far the better match. Hence he's my top-suspect.

While I have a strong suspicion, clearly more detective work needs to be done for an arrest! Am I on the right track at least?

Comment: You forget some details, The victim is computer technician, the victim know computer more than most people, also why command prompt is opened, not notepad maybe, by the way, if you solve this riddle, you will get the exact name of the culprit.

Comment: Can be assumed that a dying man is not at full capacity of his geekyness and wit and that his intention would be to most easily point a finger? If so - and if he hasn't - can be assumed that there has to be a REASON why he made things hard for the police? (Do we have to find/know it?)

Comment: Maybe he does not want someone else, including the culprit, know this riddle easily and then destroy the message, as the culprit is close to the victim, anyway the image it self is not created after the incident, but long before the incident, but the riddle is created after the incident, so we can assume  that the victim use already created image.

Comment: "by the way, if you solve this riddle, you will get the exact name of the culprit" - you should add this to the bullet points of your original post as an edit. Maybe also the information on the image-file (file-created time stamp?).

Comment: Do I need to be an IT expert as well to be able to solve this? I.e. Do I need to know some special IT tricks which I simply might not?

Comment: I think no, all those who are experienced in the puzzle will know this technique.

Comment: @BmyGuest... I tried to email you from the site linked in your profile, but the mail bounced.